# How to use Memcache session in php gae

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session, variables, memcached

I was wondering if any one could teach me how to use sessions in GAE php. I know that the usual method is to use `session_start()` in every page that wants the session to carry over and then assign variables using `$_SESSION['name']`.

But PHP on GAE is a bit confusing at times.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/?hl=en#Sessions

I have some idea on memcache but dont know how to use it to store session variable. Can any one tell how I can create a session variable so that when I redirect using header the variables will be present too.

Eg.

First.php

> ```
> session_start();
> $_SESSION['name'] = Abilash;
>
> header('location: second.php');
> ```

Second.php

> session_start();
>   echo $_SESSION['name'];  // should output Abilash.

Now how do I do that in GAE. Whenever I try to redirect using header the redirected page loads but the session variables are not passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to do anything to get sessions working, as we automatically put them into memcache by default.

Perhaps the session cookie is not being passed by your browser for the second request. I'd turn on developer tools in chrome to make sure you see that the cookie is on the request and I'd also output the result of session_start() to check it's returning true.

Comment: Here is the error I get
> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in
> /base/data/home/apps/s~*******/1.368733626510477678/Second.php on
> line 3 
<br>
Hmmm maybe there is a problem with the app.yaml I may have set it up wrongly
    handlers:
    - url: /Second.php
      script: Second.php
    - url: /
      script: First.php
      login: required
      auth_fail_action: redirect
    - url: /main
      script: main.php
      login: required

Comment: I got it working. Not exactly sure what I did. May be restructuring the app.yaml and starting from scratch worked.

Answer (score 1):

> You should not need to do anything to get sessions working, as we automatically put them into memcache by default.

was very misleading to me. It may worked back then. Nowadays, each PHP instance has it's own PHP session management by default. If you like centralized PHP session management stored in Google GAE memcache, you have to configure it!

A working possible legacy solution:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/services/access#session

  - you need legacy bundled services for PHP
  - deployable just with the beta SDK: gcloud beta app deploy